# Win32, wait for thread in main msg queue?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I created a thread in WinMain, and after that I have a classic  msg loop:

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{

    if (!done){
        GetExitCodeThread(dThread,&dwCode);
        if (dwCode!=STILL_ACTIVE){
            //thread done
        }
    }

if (!IsDialogMessage (UWnd, & msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage ( & msg );
        DispatchMessage ( & msg );
    }
}
```

This works ok, but if the thread finishes, it will not trigger until some action on the window is done (mouse, focus etc.).  How can I have the loop trigger when either message is received or thread is finished?

thank you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of testing the thread status inside the message loop, you could have the thread post a message to your UI thread (using [PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28VS.85%29.aspx)) when it completes. Then all you would need to do is handle that message in your WindowProc.

Comment: Thread messages can not be handled in a WindowPoc as they don't have an associated window (which window procedure would it be delivered to?). That said, your suggestion will work because there is no need to handle the message, the fact that it's posted is enough given the structure of the example code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at the MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx function?

Answer (score 1):

Thread handles become signalled when the thread terminates. So, instead of calling GetMessage, call MsgWaitForMultipleObjects: The return value will indicate that some messages are available - flush any messages by calling PeekMessage, or that the handle has been signalled.